# Appium: AWS Device Farm does NOT support for iOS 10.3.3 and later

Tags: appium

I am trying to run my Appium tests on AWS Device Farm. While selecting the device pool I see the below error for any  iOS device with version 10.3.3 or later.

**Error: The device is incompatible due to: AWS Device Farm currently supports Appium on iOS 10.3.3 and below.**

I just want to make sure this is a limitation with AWS device farm or Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Appium is not supported for iOS 11+ in Device Farm. But the good news is, Appium support is under test and will be released soon.

Comment: You can run tests on iOS 11 if you have XCUITESTS  test package.

Answer (score 0):

AWS now supports iOS 11. Please refer following screenshot for more details.

[image]